# How to password protect an SDcard folder using terminal in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, passwords

We have a situation whereby we have an SD card that needs a particular folder password protected.

The folder contains video files and has to be able to be accessed by an application (Kodi).

The following conditions must be met:

1. The SDcard has to be used by many different machines
2. Anyone with the password must be able to add/edit/remove files in the folder
3. Kodi should be able to access the folder as it automatically plays videos from there (which it currently already does)

**Is there any way of adding a password to the file using terminal?** It is preferable that no external application be installed to accomplish this, but I get the feeling this might be unavoidable.

I have already looked at encryption options such as cryptkeeper and GnuGP, but I'm not convinced they can meet the three conditions above.

Comment: Setting up an actually encrypted volume or similar is probably your best option, assuming the data should stay on that SD-Card. Otherwise using a password protected zip file might be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need on-the-fly encryption, so you can just "unlock" and read the files immediately without decrypting them to a second location (like gpg needs).

Cryptkeeper uses EncFS, both usually aren't installed by default in general distributions.

`cryptsetup` often is installed by default, so you could use LUKS on the whole sd card, or just a partition, or just a file.

To use LUKS on the whole card:

1. Create container: `cryptsetup luksFormat <device>`
2. Open container: `cryptsetup luksOpen <device> mapname`
3. Format container: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/mapname` (use another filesystem if desired, instead of ext4)
4. Mount container:  `mount /dev/mapper/mapname /mountpoint`
5. Copy (`cp`) files into container at `/mountpoint`

To read the files / play the videos, follow steps 2-4 then tell Kodi (or any program) to read the files at `/mountpoint`

- To use only a file on the sd card, replace `<device>` with the file. Can  create a file on the sd card with:

  `fallocate -l <length> file`
  or
  `head -c <length> /dev/zero > file`

If you're only using LUKS on a file, you could also add a small setup script containing steps 2-4, unless your system or file manager (or `gnome-disk-utility`) will unlock & mount the LUKS container with one or two clicks.

---

eCryptfs is another option, though IMO it's not as easy to set up & use as LUKS, though it's usually already installed too. See [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574110/how-to-use-ecryptfs-with-a-random-directory/574425#574425) for some information on eCryptfs with a random directory.

Comment: Thank you for this. We weren't able to get out OS (LibreElec) to bypass the security, but the steps you suggested worked in terms of it encrypted the partition. We will try and work on a solution to get the RasPi we are using to bypass the security on the card.

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, the archWiki has some good info on encryption too https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption